# custom page or standalone page?

Tags: pages, shortcode, page-template

I'm new to WordPress. I have a requirement to implement a live calculator(results updated as you type) in a WordPress site. The site has a simple theme. What is the best way to implement this?

1. Adding the calculator using custom pages? or
2. Build a simple plugin for the calculator and use shortcode? or
3. Build a standalone single page and link to WordPress site?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: A custom page, which is really a [Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) would probably be the most straightforward method.  If you wanted it to be more reusable, a plugin that added support for a shortcode that in turn displayed the calculator would be the way to go.  I would start with a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew stated, a custom page/template would be the most efficient way to display the calculator. You can leave this as a simple page, displaying just your calculator, or you can add in "the loop" below the calculator to display additional text which would be easily edited in Wordpress.